# How Can I Get Back My PPAS?

Tags: apt, updates, ppa, 17.04, ubuntu-gnome

Today I upgraded Ubuntu from 16.04 to the more updated 17.04 "Zesty Zapus." I was very happy with my new OS, loving the upgraded GTK, GNOME version and the hibernate function. However, I have noticed a problem. I heard about Firefox 55 today, and being an avid user, I updated my package lists to see if the update had come to Ubuntu's repos yet.

Sadly, the update had never came. I wasn't worried by this, but I was worried by the output given by running `sudo apt update`. When I was on Xenial, the command would output around 50 hits, and take up to a minute. On Zesty, however, the command only outputted the follwing, taking only a few seconds:

`Hit:1 za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty InRelease Ign:2 dl.google.com/deb stable InRelease Hit:3 dl.google.com/deb stable InRelease`

Since, over my association with Ubuntu, I have been filling the package lists with many external sources created by PPAs and DEB files for such things as OBS Studio, Wine and Numix, I'm a bit worried. Where have all my PPAs gone, and how do I get them back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where have my PPAs gone?

Part of the upgrade process is that third-party PPAs are disabled.

How do I get them back?

If you open Software & Updates and click the Other Software tab, hopefully your PPAs will be listed there, just not checked. If those PPAs exist in Zesty, you can re-check them.  But make sure the version says Zesty and not Xenial!

In the future, you can back up PPAs using [aptik](https://launchpad.net/apt-toolkit)